# Subversion and Siteminder

Tags: svn, siteminder

Has anyone implements Subversion with Siteminder as authentication provider ? If yes, would it be possible to provide an overview of how the whole setup is done ?

Since I am using only HTTP authentication, I think it would be easier to integrate with SM, but I am not able to find much help on this on the net.

Is there any pitfall with this setup ? is this even possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVN with Siteminder has been implemented and is working now. Since there is not much of information out there on this, I would like to post the overview of steps followed:

1. Cookie based authentcation was disabled on Siteminder end
2. HTTP AUTH was enabled (in Siteminder) and all webdav methods were added to policy server to be handled by SiteMinder
3. Authentication was disabled on apache end (HTTP Auth) for SVN

Comment: By HTTP AUTH you mean the standard HTTP Basic Authentication Scheme in SiteMinder?
What Realm(s) did you create to protect it? Did you create a realm per repository or did you end up going more fine-grained?

What about 'methods', was it just GET/POST or were there other methods?

Answer (score 1):

Look for information about **Apache** and Siteminder as Apache is responsible for the HTTP transport stuff in Subversion